# What kind of presents are or is in passive sentences?

Tags: grammar

I have read the use and a couple of examples of "kind of + plural noun", but I'm still confused what to use, "is" or "are" in the follows:

- What kind of presents ____ normally given at birthdays in your homeland?

So, the "___" should be "is" or "are"?

Answer (score 1):

Simplify it by keeping everything singular or plural:

> What **kind** of **present is** normally given at birthdays in your homeland?
>   What **kinds** of **presents are** normally given at birthdays in your homelands?

I suspect the more common question would take the plural form, as there are typically multiple presents (each of a different type) given.

But if what you really want is a suggestion for your own gift, then be more direct about it:

> What kind of present **should I bring** to the birthday party?